# Why does my .scan function from the Python-NMAP module show 'str' Attribute Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmap

I installed first the nmap module in PyCharm but received as many others the error for my nmap.PortScanner function.

Therefore, I uninstalled nmap and installed **python-nmap**.

Now, I have however the problem with executing the command:

```
import nmap
ns = nmap.PortScanner
ns.scan('My.IP.Add.ress', '1-1024', '-v')
print(ns.scaninfo())
```

I get for the second line the error message:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_nmap_path'**

However, watching all examples of this, show precisely these lines of code. 
Can somebody please explain what is happening?

My editor also shows for ns.scaninfo() a warning that the parameter 'self' is not filled. Again, this is not what the examples show. I am very confused by this.

As always, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the root cause, but you're missing some brackets on the second line. It should be `ns = nmap.PortScanner()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since posting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092781/why-does-my-scan-function-from-the-python-nmap-module-show-str-attribute-erro#comment93082584_53092781) I've become convinced that it is the root cause, so posting as an answer.)

You're missing some brackets on the second line. It should read:

```
ns = nmap.PortScanner()
```

As it is, you're storing the `PortScanner` class in `ns`, as opposed to an object of that class. This means that when you call `ns.scan` its first parameter (which it's expecting to be `self`, the `PortScanner` object with an `_nmap_path` attribute) is actually a string, which doesn't have the attribute. The same reason is behind your editor's warning about the `self` parameter not being filled, too.

Comment: Thank you very much. This truly did the trick. I must have looked at my code and compared it so many times but the parenthesis, I did not even notice.